# Print controller does not appear

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios-4.2, xcode3.2

I am working on an application for iPad. I am using Xcode 3.2.6. Earlier I had ios 4.2 in my iPad. Now I have upgraded it to 5.0. I have implemented print functionality in my app. When I was using ios 4.2 the print functionality was working fine in iPad, but after upgrading it to ios 5.0, the print controller does not appear. This is making me mad. I can't figure out why this is happening. Can any one help me regarding this problem?

Regards

PC

Comment: Upgrade your Xcode! On a more serious note, have you set breakpoints where the print controller should be called... where does it go? Step through and find out what's happening, to begin with.

Comment: @Luke: thanks for the quick reply Luke. If I upgrade xcode to 4.2, will there be any issues in my project? Because I am close to delivery date and I don't want any issues to come up at this time. Also, is upgrading Xcode the only way to fix it?

Comment: It's more of a general thing, to update Xcode... eventually Apple will phase Xcode 3.x out and you won't be able to submit apps with it. For now, try my other suggestion first and/or try to provide any other info or code if you can. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use present from Bar Button on iPad:

```
[printController presentFromBarButtonItem:YourPrintButton animated:YES completionHandler:YourCompletionHandler];
```

on iPhone it does not matter.

B